# Writing a custom Deserializer for homogenuous Collections with unbounded generics

Tags: java, jackson

I'm struggling to deserialize a `Collection<Collection<?>>` using Jackson. When deserializing the serialized object Jackson converts them into a `LinkedHashMap` instead of `Item`:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class JsonTest {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Test
    void main() throws JsonProcessingException {
        Set<Integer> firstSet = Set.of(1, 2, 3);
        Set<Item> secondSet = Set.of(new Item("abc"), new Item("123"));
        Root root = new Root(List.of(firstSet, secondSet));

        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(root);
        System.out.println(json);

        Root parsed = mapper.readValue(json, Root.class);
        assertEquals(firstSet, parsed.data().get(0));
        assertEquals(secondSet, parsed.data().get(1));
        // the assertion above fails:
        // Expected :[Item[id=abc], Item[id=123]]
        // Actual   :[{id=abc}, {id=123}]
    }
}

record Root(List<Set<?>> data) {}

record Item(String id) {}
```

```
// build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.0'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

My first idea was to replace the `Set<?>` with a custom container class that contains an additional type hint and write a custom deserializer:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class JsonTest {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Test
    void main() throws JsonProcessingException {
        TypedList<Item> secondSet = new TypedList<>(Item.class, List.of());
        Root root = new Root(secondSet);

        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(root);
        System.out.println(json);

        Root parsed = mapper.readValue(json, Root.class);
        assertEquals(secondSet, parsed.data());
    }
}

class TypedCollectionDeserializer<T> extends StdDeserializer<TypedList<T>> {
    public TypedCollectionDeserializer() {
        super(TypedList.class);
    }

    @Override
    public TypedList<T> deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        Class<T> valueType = getTypeClass(p);
        String dataKey = p.nextFieldName();
        if (!dataKey.equals("data")) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        List<T> list = deserializeData(p, valueType);
        // skip END_ARRAY
        p.nextToken();
        return new TypedList<>(valueType, list);
    }

    private Class<T> getTypeClass(JsonParser p) throws IOException {
        String typeKey = p.nextFieldName();
        if (!typeKey.equals("type")) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        String typeValue = p.nextTextValue();
        try {
            return (Class<T>) Class.forName(typeValue);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("unexpected type " + typeValue, e);
        }
    }

    private List<T> deserializeData(JsonParser p, Class<T> valueType) throws IOException {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
        JsonToken jsonToken = p.nextToken();
        if (jsonToken != JsonToken.START_ARRAY) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        JsonToken maybeStart = p.nextToken();
        if (maybeStart == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
            do {
                T t = p.readValueAs(valueType);
                if (t != null) {
                    list.add(t);
                }
            } while (p.nextToken() == JsonToken.START_OBJECT);
        }
        return list;
    }
}

record Root(@JsonDeserialize(using = TypedCollectionDeserializer.class) TypedList<?> data) {}

record Item(String id) {}

@JsonPropertyOrder({"type", "data"})
record TypedList<T>(Class<T> type, List<T> data) {}
```

But this looks like I'm re-doing Jackson's own code to deserialize `Collection`s. Is there perhaps a more idiomatic way?

Comment: because the type-erasure that jackson cont find any type to deserialize, so why not using some type data, and using `readValue(String content, Class<T> valueType)` to deserialize

Comment: I am aware of Java's type erasure. My example is part of a bigger code base where `Root` can be deep inside an object structure, so `mapper.readValue(String, Class)` is not possible

Comment: so your probleam is become how to convert `LinkedHashMap` to `Item`, your no  way to config jackson to return `Item` in this example, you can track jackson source code to learn more

Comment: Okay, I have abandoned this approach by replacing the unbounded wildcards with concrete types. This is easier for me because it works out of the box without further headaches. The original data structures are more complex, the `Item` class contained more generic fields that would be incorrectly deserialized, too